# How can I have concurrent read access to video devices on Linux?

Tags: linux, v4l

I want to be able to have multiple readers on a video device file - one using it to stream video and another using it for computer vision processing. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/) to create two virtual video devices and use your data stream splitter of choice (`tee`, etc.) to send the video to both devices.